# Canceling my two week notice to go to a remote job

Tags: notice-period, work-life-balance, telecommute, remote-work

I gave my 2 week notice at my current employer who has been very good to me over the past several years. The work has gotten a little bit stale and boring but overall I like seeing people and going for walks at lunch. Life is kind of simple and I don't mind it. I definitely feel like my skills and ability could be stretched a bit further than they currently are but I don't want to bite off more than I can chew and work more than 40 hours. Some of the people I work with constantly need my assistance even though they are more senior than me. a promotion has been promised in the past but HR I learned is the true bottleneck and why that promise was broken and not kept. I've come to terms with that and I'm okay with it. Things will work out eventually is how I looked at it. Just this year I actually got a raise for the first time in three years although I'm pretty sure I'm one of the highest-paid on my team so I don't really have room to complain. we recently had a change at the top and there's a lot of new leadership shaking things up and trying to save money wherever they can or justify everything with data. The business has sort of gone from a mom-and-pop feel to a large Enterprise feel. I don't really mind that changed so long as whatever trickles down doesn't affect my work-life balanceand I don't get the feeling that it will in the near future.

Recently I was offered a 100% remote job that pays 30% more. The decision to leave has weighed on me heavily. First I thought about how much I'm going to miss the beautiful building and the people/social interaction and how that could impact my mental health. Now that those emotions have subsided I'm starting to feel like remote work might not be for me because I am single and live alone. Lots of people say remote work is no big deal but they usually have a husband or wife at home in the evening so it's not a huge deal for them. But for me I think my situation is unique in that I have no one and not enough is written online about this scenario. I have some family that lives nearby but that's not the same as having regular contact. I've looked into co-working spaces but when I went to tour them there aren't many people there. I'm worried I will be isolated and lonely. so basically in two days I will have a laptop from my new employer and no official office to go to. The thought of that is a little bit mortifying. I've never done remote work before and I've heard that it's more about your output then just showing up to the office which I can understand but I'm also wondering if I'll makethe bar they set given the amount of pay they're giving me.

I also found out that this new company doesn't like commercial activities or moonlighting outside of work. Ironically I thought this was going to be a better job because of the flexibility I could work on my own business I'm trying to build outside of work. I did get an exception from HR because they got more relaxed on this policy recently but it still gives me a little bit of hesitation.

So to summarize, I highly value work-life balance, working on my own business outside of work, and pay.

I have two days left at my current employer and I'm seriously considering walking into my boss's office and asking if I can keep my job because I don't believe remote work would be right for me. Embarrassment aside, I'm wondering if this is the right move? I question whether I'll regret the decision to cancel if I do get to stay at my current job, leaving all that money on the table. Right now I'm mainly concerned about my mental health. Sure, I could give it a try for several months and see how it goes but there's no guarantee I'll be able to go back to my current job for a while if they have no open seats. Sometimes it feels like society puts these artificial burdens on us to progress through these sort of actions but maybe it's not worth it to move on. looking for words of advice or encouragement in either direction.

Has anyone else decided not to take a remote opportunity and stay at their current office job for mental health reasons?

Comment: The similar question you asked a few days ago was closed as off-topic. In this one however, I can't find any question at all. Can you please edit the post to contain a clear and answerable question. Some guidance: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated the text to have a question at the end. I'm just trying to figure out if my reasons are justified for canceling and trying to stay at my current job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only person you have to justify anything to is yourself. It's your life, your health etc,.